# INVALID VALUE ("254") for a folder in TYPO3

Tags: typo3

I am new to TYPO3. I recently upgraded TYPO3 to 6.2 LTS from 4.5 following steps from some websites. Everything seems to be working okay.

I created a test folder and tried to edit the folder. I got INVALID VALUE("254") in Page Type. Here is the image

https://i.stack.imgur.com/h85Hx.png

I looked at logs, developers logs, and searched Google but I did not find anything relevant to the problem.  Any idea on where to start?

PS: I didn't have enough reputation to add images directly. So, sorry for the link.

Answer (score 0):

254 is the page type "Folder". It is very strange that this should be illegal. It's working here on a 6.2 installation.

Maybe it's a TypoScript configuration that disallows folders as subpage types at the parent page.

Comment: Can you explain a little bit more about it or point to some pages. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have you already tried "database compare" function in your install tool? Looks for me like a update problem.

Comment: Yes, I did  Compare current database with specification from install tool -> Important actions.  there are some errors like: invalid default value for 'zzz_deleted_email' but I guess they are not related to the problem.